# How to deregister button click?

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
             } else if (buttonClicked.getParent() != button.getParent()) {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                 buttonClicked = null;
                }       
            }

     };
```

I press one button, and then another and now it check if both button are from the same parent, if they are, it proceed inside the if statement. BUT, if they're not from the same parent the code exits the else if statement down to buttonClicked = null;. Here, I have a problem. After second click comes 3rd one, and I need to deregister the first click like it never happend, cause now I need to compare 2nd and 3rd click. What happens in my case, 1st click stays active all the way, and waits until the condition from the else if statement checks positive, and proceeds to the next if statement. And that's not good for me.

So, how to deregister first click like it never happened, and make only latest two click be active, so in this case 2nd and 3rd? And when I press the 4th button to deregister 2nd.

Comment: That might solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195321/remove-an-onclick-listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. This code will change the second button to first clicked button if they don't have the same tag.

```
//This has to be a global variable so that last clicked button can be retained. 
//Earlier when it was local to the listener so its value was always set to null whenever a button was clicked
private Button buttonClicked=null;

final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
         Button button = (Button) v;
         button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

         if (buttonClicked == null) {
                // first button is clicked
                buttonClicked = button;
         } 

//else if (buttonClicked.getParent() != button.getParent()) {//THIS was the culprit
 else if (buttonClicked != button) {//Direct comparison of buttons was the solution                    
// second button is clicked
 if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        //Moved this line inside if condition so that button click is only set to null when there is a match.
        buttonClicked = null;
        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        /*
                        * IMPORTANT: change the color here to the original unclicked 
button color. Now in the else condition i.e. there was not a match we need to make the last clicked button to look like an unclicked button so we need to change it to original color and then make the new clicked button to be the current clicked button.
                            */
                            buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                            //Make the second button the current cliked one
                            buttonClicked = button;

                    }

                }       
            }
     };
```

Comment: Nope, this did not work. In fact, this made it worse. :) Now at some point I have 4 button selected as correct. :)

Comment: did you change the color back to the original color in the inner else condition. Also I am making a change in the code please check

Comment: Yes, this works. Can you explain me what exactly did you do here? Also, you said to change color to original, but I've tried that, but success. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: By original color I mean to change the color bak to its unpressed state. You change the color of button to 0x003333 when it is clicked but when you press second button which is not a match you need to change the color of the first button to what other buttons look like. I don't know if you actually need it or not. Also check my comments in the code, I have added more.

Comment: This code above actually does work. I dont know how I thought it was working. I tried it again yesterday and it doesn't. And yes I need to change color back to original, check [this out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960315/how-to-clear-color-of-a-button)

Comment: try this it should work buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x000000));

Comment: Nope. This code does not work at all. It now compares button from the same layout also. Plus, it does not change color of the first clicked button to default when the next is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to understand what exactly you are doing, so rather than lead you by the hand I will try to clarify your algorithm. The pseudocode would look something like this, I think.

```
When clicking a button with nothing else selected ("clicked button" is null):
    Set the background colour
    Disable the button
    Note clicked button
When clicking a button with its pair "clicked button" selected (different parents, equal tags)
    Set the background colour
    Disable the button
    Note second clicked button
When clicking a button with a non-pair "clicked button" selected (different parents, different tags)
    Reset the "clicked button" background colour
    Enable the "clicked button"
    Set "clicked button" to null
    if "second clicked button" is not null
        Reset the "second clicked button" background colour
        Enable the "second clicked button"
        Set "second clicked button" to null
    Perform processing in "When clicking a button with nothing else selected"
```

I've seen you have had multiple questions around this problem; the source, I think, is that you do not have the algorithm clear yet. Note that this algorithm means that you cannot deselect a button from a pair, due to having disabled them. Think about how you would allow deselection - if the clicked buttons are enabled, then we need to handle a second click.

Comment: I only disable buttons if the pair is correct, so the user cannot use that buttons anymore.

Comment: @marjanbaz: Well, in that case my above pseudocode is perhaps correct.