# Disable OnClickListener Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have an `OnClickListener` on an image in my app. It allows the user to skip to a different part of the app if desired. The way the app runs, they can only use it 3 times.

My issue is, I want to get fancy pants. So I added an `R.anim.fade_out` animation to make the image fade out after all 3 times were used. I am using a counter decreased by one in another method.

The issue is, when the original method is recalled, it throws a `Null Reference Exception` because it can't find the image to set the `OnClickListener`. I tried wrapping it in an `If/Else If` statement:

```
if(skipsAllowed > 0){

            skipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v){

                    if(skipsAllowed > 0){
                        try {
                            skippedPage();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }else  if(skipsAllowed == 0){
            skipFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            skipButton.startAnimation(skipFadeOut);
        }
```

This still didn't work. Any ideas on how to stop this?

I instantiate the `ImageView` at the start of every new call to this `Activity`, should I be placing that inside my **If/Else** If?

Comment: are you setting on click listener all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `skipsAllowed == 0` unregister `onClickListener`

See [Remove an onclick listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195321/remove-an-onclick-listener)

By the way, you should review your code, we usually set a **click listener** only **once**.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped. You were right, I moved my click listener up to the `onCreate()`, and simply unregistered it when it was time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

Simple: `skipButton.setOnClickListener(null)`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an exception because you are passing **null context** to `loadAnimation`.

You can get application context with :
`getApplicationContext()`

And after animation start you should set you button to **INVISIBLE** to completely hide the **skip button**.

```
Animation skipFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
        skipButton.startAnimation(skipFadeOut);
        skipButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually saw that right after posting, I should have edited the question. It all works like it should.